# Cordova screenshot outside application

Tags: javascript, java, android, cordova

When I let my app running in the background, the Cordova screenshot plugin seems to only accept in-app-screenshot, and I want to make my application can do the screenshot in any application (outside or inside), just like what phone-user sees

current code :

```
    navigator.screenshot.URI(function(error,response){
        if(error){
            console.error(error);
            return;
        }
        console.log(response.URI)
    }, 100);
```

Comment: use the screen recorder of the IDE... what you "want" is not possible.

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible - your app of course can not take screenshots of random screens, only the ones it controls.

As a user, I am very happy about that - otherwise I had to expect anything I type or receive to be screenshotted by other apps.